# Вывести все товары и количество проданных товаров за указанный период одним запросом Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть 2 таблицы

- `my_data_1c` - список товаров
- `my_data_1c_nomenclature` - список продаж этих товаров по дате

Одним запросом хочу вывести все товары и количество проданных товаров за период (например с начало года)
Имею такой запрос

```
SELECT my_data_1c.id
     , SUM(my_data_1c_nomenclature.count) as count
FROM my_data_1c 
LEFT JOIN my_data_1c_nomenclature ON 
       my_data_1c_nomenclature.id_product = my_data_1c.id_product 
WHERE my_data_1c.visible='1' 
      AND my_data_1c_nomenclature.id_product IN ('e3fece5f-3e42-11e9-80f6-1c1b0d3319f5', '1ad14c13-31cf-11ea-812e-1c1b0d3319f5')    
      AND (
           my_data_1c_nomenclature.cdate > '2021-01-01 00:00:00' 
           AND my_data_1c_nomenclature.cdate < '2021-03-09 09:20:19'
          )    
GROUP BY my_data_1c_nomenclature.id_product
```

Вроде бы все хорошо но вот `SUM(my_data_1c_nomenclature.count)` выводит сумму за весь период а не за указанный. Как победить?

Comment: *Как победить?* Условной агрегацией. `SUM(CASE WHEN дата BETWEEN начало AND конец THEN сумма ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: если сумму продаж надо за период, то этот период надо в условия джойна запихивать,иначе рисккуете получить не весь список товаров фильтруя в where

Answer (score 0):

Если вам продажи нужны за период, то и джойньте данные за этот период, иначе фильтруя в `where` вы получите только те твоары, которые были проданы, а не все (как указано в заголовке вопроса).

```
SELECT p.id_product
     , SUM(s.count) as count
FROM my_data_1c AS p
LEFT JOIN my_data_1c_nomenclature AS s ON  (
         s.id_product = p.id_product
         s.cdate between '2021-01-01 00:00:00'  AND  '2021-03-09 09:20:19'
       )
WHERE p.visible = 1
      AND p.id_product IN ('e3fece5f-3e42-11e9-80f6-1c1b0d3319f5', '1ad14c13-31cf-11ea-812e-1c1b0d3319f5')        
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

Comment: К сожалению данный метод выводит аналогичный результат

Comment: @lidovsci приведите пример данных, на которых данный метод работает не так как ожидается (с точки зрения суммарных значений результат соответствует вашему)

Comment: Ссылка на результат https://abra7kadabra7.kz/des.jpg и ответ сколько должно быть. У меня выводить 9200 это за весь период а сначала года должно быть 1840

Comment: @lidovsci уберите из запроса группировку и гляньте что получается. у вас в джойне скорее всего не хватает каких-то условий, в итоге вместо одной строки получается 5 (1840*5=9200)

Comment: если убрать группировку тогда выводится общая сумма результата  9200+55,5

Comment: @lidovsci убрать группировку это убрать `group by` и сделать `select p.id, s.*`

Comment: тоже не работает, данный метод выводит рандомный результат

Comment: @lidovsci данный метод выводит не рандомный результат, а исходные данные которые вы суммируете. вот и разберитесь сначала ас тем, что суммировать, а потом уже смотрите нужная сумма получилась или нет. Создайте сниппет где-нибудь с тестовыми данными - продемонстрируйте проблему не только на картинке.